# Verify that 4(29!)+5! is divisible by 31.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Verify that 4(29!)+5! is divisible by 31. How do I work this out? Step by step explanation please!

Comment: And how do we know you aren't cheating?

Comment: Hint: $(p-1)! \equiv -1$ (mod $p$).

Comment: so then I have (29!)= -1(mod 29) where do I go from here with simplifying?

Comment: also should i do the 29! and 5! separately?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778918/verify-that-4295-is-divisible-by-31

Comment: @Goos, has OP posted the same question twice? If so, then please flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes.  And OP has also copied the nonsense comment on my answer below from [here](http://pat-rossi.com/MTH4436/homework/hw5_3.pdf).

Comment: @Goos, OP seems to be quite a piece of work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

\begin{align*}
30! &\equiv -1 \pmod{31} \\
30 &\equiv -1 \pmod{31} \\
\implies 29! &\equiv \quad ? \pmod{31} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: but 29! is such a large number how do I break it down?

Comment: @Lil You know what $30!$ is congruent to.  You also know that $30! = 30 \cdot 29!$.

Comment: ok so far I have this... 
15!≡(15!)(-1)^2(mod17)
   ≡ (15!)(16)^2 (mod 17)
   ≡ 16! (16) (mod17)
   ≡ (-1)(-1) (mod 17)
is this correct so far?

Comment: Why, Lil, are you working modulo 17? 17 has nothing to do with the problem. Forget 17, and look at what Goos is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

$30! \equiv -1 \pmod{31}$, so $29! \equiv \frac{30!}{30} \equiv \frac{-1}{30} \pmod{31}$. So,

$4(29!) + 5! \equiv 4(\frac{-1}{30}) + 120 \equiv \frac{-4}{30} - 4 \equiv \frac{120}{30} - 4 \equiv 0 \pmod{31}$.